# Is there any motorbike rental in Kuala Lumpur?

Tags: rental, motorcycles, kuala-lumpur

I would like to know if there's any motorbike rental service in Kuala Lumpur?
How much would be daily and what are the documents needed to rent the bike?
How much deposit do you have to pay up front?

If anybody knows a website, I'd appreciate if you post it on the comment section.

Comment: Who decided that legit, on-topic "is X possible in Y location" questions like this one suddenly became price shopping? And more to the point, why didn't they discuss it first on meta? Voting to re-open

Comment: @user568458 "How much would be daily and... How much deposit do you have to pay up front?" looks like a price-shopping question, to me.

Comment: @David that's a minor part of the question (and anyway is asking for *typical* prices, i.e. budgeting, not shopping for specific providers). You're free to edit that part out and leave the (100% on topic) rest of the question